# Parent state change generates a child re-render when the child does not have that state as a prop [Virtual DOM]

Tags: reactjs

I've been doing some tests about changing a parent state property affecting directly with a new child re-render.

1. Using onMouseEnter/onMouseLeave methods of a parent to change "isMouseOver" state --> Affects to child.
2. Using useHover hook
   implemented using parent ref and event listener --> Affects to child
3. Using css Hover  --> Doesn't affect to child

The problem is that parent "isMouseOver" state or "isHovered" shouldn't affect to child because it's not a child prop.

In child, I'm passing as a props "top" and "left", both setted in child styles, calculating a new top.

For each parent hover, child handleTop is triggered, giving me to undersantd that child is re-rendered for each state change of parent but in my head it has no logic because it should not re-render thanks to the virtual dom, so maybe is due the way of setting child style.

*CODE:*

****PARENT****

```
export default function App() {
  const [isMouseOver, setIsMouseOver] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [elementRef, isHovered] = useHover();

  const handleMouseOver = (isMouseOver: boolean): void => {
    setIsMouseOver(isMouseOver);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.App}>
      <div
        className={
          isMouseOver
            ? `${styles.element} ${styles.element___isMouseOver}`
            : styles.element
        }
        onMouseEnter={() => handleMouseOver(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => handleMouseOver(false)}
      >
        {/* <div ref={elementRef} className={styles.element}> */}
        {/* <div className={styles.element}> */}
        <PopOverComponent top={0} left={200} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**CHILD:**

```
interface PopOverComponentProps {
  top: number;
  left: number;
}

export default function PopOverComponent({ top, left }: PopOverComponentProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("top changes", top);
  }, [top]);

  const handleTop = (): number => {
    const newTop = top + 25;
    console.log("handleTop is triggered", newTop);

    return newTop;
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ top: handleTop(), left: left }} className={styles.popOver} />
  );
}
```

[Playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-gagarin-yk5zf?file=/src/components/pop-over/pop-over.component.tsx:88-547)

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `React.memo()` for avoiding re-rendering stuff in react component. [Avoiding React component re-renders with React.memo](https://aheadcreative.co.uk/articles/avoiding-react-component-re-renders-with-react-memo/)

Example :

```
interface PopOverComponentProps {
  top: number;
  left: number;
}

 const PopOverComponent = React.memo(({ top, left }: PopOverComponentProps) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("top changes", top);
  }, [top]);

  const handleTop = (): number => {
    const newTop = top + 25;
    console.log("handleTop is triggered", newTop);

    return newTop;
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ top: handleTop(), left: left }} className={styles.popOver} />
  );
})

export default PopOverComponent
```